# Change the position of Outlook Addin Context Menu

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, add-in

I am trying to add a context menu for my contact Item in an Outlook Addin Project.. But the Menu appears at the bottom... How can I set it as first Item in Menu... ?

```
var contextButton = commandBar.Controls.Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, missing, missing, 0, true) as Office.CommandBarButton;
```

Please Help me. This is the Image of the Menu on Mail Items.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When calling Controls.Add, one of the parameters is Before. Find the Copy menu item and pass it as the Before parameter.

Comment: Hi, I searched everywhere on google, But I couldnt find What Id copy menu Item has...

Comment: Both Id and FaceId = 19.